# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to build google api client

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, noclassdeffounderror

today i added the google play services library to my project. I have followed the instructions which are given on http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

Screenshot of my Settings: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwe9sI6XZ6rcZGZzdmlaQjVheDA/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is when I try to execute the following code, a noclassdeffounderror exception raises.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    .build();
```

In the logcat the exception looks like

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d02930)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder
    at com.gmail.mhofer4991.at.taptorotate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5074)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Force finishing activity com.example.taptorotate/com.gmail.mhofer4991.at.taptorotate.MainActivity
```

I also have cleaned and rebuilt the project.

It's driving me crazy that i cannot solve the problem. I know there are already other threads with the same topic and I also tried some solutions which were suggested there but none of them worked for me. Please help me out!

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having a same problem and cannot figure it out..

Comment: @Majstor see my answer! I had the same problem. =|

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
      com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder
```

I was using the below dependency on the application build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

I changed it to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
```

I updated the Google Play Services (Rev 26) and Google Repository(Rev 20).

After that the exception doesn't occur.

Try to use individual APIs and corresponding build.gradle descriptions as mensioned in the following page,
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure

Answer (score 0):

Try to add obfuscation rules for the Google API's if you have minifyEnabled or ProGuard set to true: 
[ProGuard Configuration](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-android-sample/proguard-google-api-client.txt)

Answer (score 0):

tryin to work with an implementation of Google Drive in Android i´ve found this error message pointing some classes like:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
```

I have found that the real problem is the [limit of 64K references](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) when we add dependencies related to GoogleApiClient, so adding multidex support solved my problem:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
...
...
```